# An object method is required for non static, field method

Tags: c#, object, methods, static, required

I've no experience of using C# but as part of one of our college modules we have to create a slot machine application. We created a Gambler class and I have to make a CheckBalance class where I will call the Token method from the Gambler class. But I get the error that is mentioned in the thread title.

```
Int tokens = Gambler.Tokens;
```

The above line is where I am getting my error.
This is my code:

```
enter code herenamespace CasinoClasslibrary
{
public class Gambler
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public int Age { get; private set; }

    public long CreditCardNum { get; private set; }

    public int Tokens { get; public set; }

    public string Username { get; private set; }

    public string  Password { private get; public set; }

    public Gambler(string Name, int Age, long CreditCardNum, int Tokens, string Username,  string   Password)
    {
        this.Name = Name;
        this.Age = Age;
        this.CreditCardNum = CreditCardNum;
        this.Tokens = Tokens;
        this.Username = Username;
        this.Password = Password;
    }
}

public class Cashout : Gambler
{
    public Boolean CheckBalance()
    {

        int tokens = Gambler.Tokens;
        return true;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Since you are inheriting from `Gambler` I suspect that you need to access base.Tokens like:

```
public Boolean CheckBalance()
{
    int tokens = base.Tokens; //here
    return true;
}
```

Otherwise since `Toakens` is an instance member you have to create object of `Gambler` and then access it.

There are other errors in your code as well. You haven't defined a default *(parameter less)* constructor in your base class and you need to call the existing base constructor in your child class.

```
public class Cashout : Gambler
{
    public Cashout()
        : base("",0, 0, 1, "", "") //something like this
    {
    }
    public Boolean CheckBalance()
    {
        int tokens = base.Tokens;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because Cashout inherits from Gambler you can just do this. This is because the `Cashout` instance will have a `Tokens` property as well.

```
public class Cashout : Gambler
{    
  public Boolean CheckBalance()
  {

    int tokens = Tokens;
    return true;
  }
}
```

However, if you intended the method to be static, you will need an instance of `Gambler` to access that property and this should be passed into the static method as such.

```
public class Cashout : Gambler
{    
  public static Boolean CheckBalance(Gambler myGambler)
  {

    int tokens = myGambler.Tokens;
    return true;
  }
}
```

Finally, if you intended this `Tokens` property to be static itself, you need to declare it as such

```
public static int Tokens;
```

You may also want a static constructor to set it up.

Answer (score 1):

`Tokens` is not static method but you try to access it through static construct (class level).

can make this work by declaring it static (although that's not likely what you want)

```
public static int Tokens { get; public set; }
```

or by instantiating Gambler

```
new Gambler().Tokens;
```